# Creating pandas column from two columns of strings contains NAs

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have two columns containing strings and NAs and I want to combine them into 1. I feel this should be fairly simple but cannot seem to get it to work or find the answer on here. Below is the result I am after.

```
S1  S2  S
A   Nan A
A   Nan A
A   Nan A
A   Nan A
Nan C   C
Nan C   C
Nan C   C
Nan C   C
Nan Nan Nan
Nan Nan Nan
Nan Nan Nan
B   Nan B
B   Nan B
B   Nan B
B   Nan B
B   Nan B
```

I thought `df['S'] = df['S1']+ df['S2']` would work but no.

Really feel like there will be an obvious fix, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df['S_new'] = df['S1'].combine_first(df['S2'])
print (df)
     S1   S2    S S_new
0     A  NaN    A     A
1     A  NaN    A     A
2     A  NaN    A     A
3     A  NaN    A     A
4   NaN    C    C     C
5   NaN    C    C     C
6   NaN    C    C     C
7   NaN    C    C     C
8   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
9   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
10  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
11    B  NaN    B     B
12    B  NaN    B     B
13    B  NaN    B     B
14    B  NaN    B     B
15    B  NaN    B     B
```